# display scaling keeps reverting

Tags: gnome, 20.04, display, scaling

I am running ubuntu 20.04 on a virtual machine and whenever I resume my host computer from sleep the display scaling factor gets reset to 100% (I want it at 200%)
there's an old similar question regarding this on ubuntu 17.04 which uses a perl script to constantly monitor the value and change it back if it ever resets (which is a workaround but it would still be ok for me) unfortunately it seems like it doesn't work for a virtual machine, for reference [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909235/17-04-display-scaling-reverting-to-1-after-resume-from-suspend) is the post.
also I've seen a lot of bugs talk about a gnome text bug but that's not the bug I'm facing

Comment: I hit the same. Yoga X1 Gen6.